# Pandas reset inner level of MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF in the following format:

```
                   col1    col2
ID          Date
 1    1993-12-31      4       6
      1994-12-31      8       5
      1995-12-31      4       7
      1996-12-31      3       3
 2    2000-12-31      7       8
      2001-12-31      5       9
      2002-12-31      8       4
```

And I want to reset the 'Date' index giving the following:

```
             col1    col2
ID    Date
 1       0      4       6
         1      8       5
         2      4       7
         3      3       3
 2       0      7       8
         1      5       9
         2      8       4
```

I thought simply `df.reset_index(level='Date', inplace=True, drop=True)` would do it, but it does not.

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior I was expecting from `reset_index` too...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays` and `groupby` + `cumcount`.

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [df.index.get_level_values(0), df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()],
    names=['ID', 'Date'])
```

```
df
         col1  col2
ID Date            
1  0        4     6
   1        8     5
   2        4     7
   3        3     3
2  0        7     8
   1        5     9
   2        8     4
```

This won't generalise to N levels, but there should be a `df.index.set_levels` equivalent I'm forgetting...

Comment: What is I want to do the same thing but on multi-level columns rather than index?  One way is to probably transpose twice, but apparently it changes data types everywhere.  Is there a way to do it without transposing?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Using `set_index` and `cumcount`:

```
tmp = df.reset_index('Date', drop=True)
tmp.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().rename('Date'), append=True)

         col1  col2
ID Date
1  0        4     6
   1        8     5
   2        4     7
   3        3     3
2  0        7     8
   1        5     9
   2        8     4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can groupby `ID`, then reset the index on each group using `apply`:

```
new_df = (df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('ID'))
          .apply(lambda x: x.reset_index()).drop(['ID','Date'],1))

new_df.index = new_df.index.rename(['ID','Date'])

>>> new_df
         col1  col2
ID Date            
1  0        4     6
   1        8     5
   2        4     7
   3        3     3
2  0        7     8
   1        5     9
   2        8     4
```

Answer (score 3):

## New Answer

Not as cool as the old answer but I'd rather be accurate than cool.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count
d = defaultdict(count)

lbl = []
for a, *_ in df.index.values:
    lbl.append(next(d[a]))

lvl = pd.RangeIndex(max(lbl) + 1)

df.set_index(df.index.set_labels(lbl, 1).set_levels(lvl, 1))

         col1  col2
ID Date            
1  0        4     6
   1        8     5
   2        4     7
   3        3     3
2  0        7     8
   1        5     9
   2        8     4
```

---

## OLD ANSWER

### Do Not Use

I misread the question.  I didn't see that the new index needed to reset for every group.

Hopefully useful to someone.

### You can use [**`pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html)

```
n = 1
lvl = df.index.levels[n]
new_lvl = pd.RangeIndex(len(lvl))
new_idx = df.index.set_levels(new_lvl, n)
df.set_index(new_idx)

         col1  col2
ID Date            
1  0        4     6
   1        8     5
   2        4     7
   3        3     3
2  4        7     8
   5        5     9
   6        8     4
```

---

### One-line

Yay! `\o/`

```
df.set_index(df.index.set_levels(pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index.levels[1])), 1))

         col1  col2
ID Date            
1  0        4     6
   1        8     5
   2        4     7
   3        3     3
2  4        7     8
   5        5     9
   6        8     4
```

---

### In place

```
df.index.set_levels(pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index.levels[1])), 1, inplace=True)
df

         col1  col2
ID Date            
1  0        4     6
   1        8     5
   2        4     7
   3        3     3
2  4        7     8
   5        5     9
   6        8     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda _group:_group.reset_index())
```

******vrsions warning***:

- the following behavior was tested on pandas version: **"1.1.2"**
- according to [Pandas - Release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/index.html):

  -> it seem that from version **1.3.0** may be a fix that could effect this method , see [Bug-Fix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#:%7E:text=Bug%20in%20GroupBy.apply()%20where%20a%20MultiIndex%20would%20be%20created%20instead%20of%20an%20Index%20when%20used%20on%20a%20RollingGroupby%20object%20(GH39732))

***Example:***

let's create MultiIndex df by concatenate dictionary with 2 df, such as the key of each level will be appended into the index level

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_df = pd.concat({'First':pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4),index=range(4)),
                    'Second':pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4),index=range(41,45))})
```

[image]

**result:**

```
result_df = raw_df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda _group:_group.reset_index(drop=True))
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to show the output of your command applied to the given data frame and whether this really matches the output the OP wants.